# How can I crop a 3D object in the format .obj or .noff?

Tags: graphics3d

bunny= Import[ "http://exampledata.wolfram.com/bunny.noff.gz" ]

How can I crop this .noff object to get something similar to the attached photo? The 2nd image has 30% cropped and the last image has 50% cropped.[image]

Comment: try [`ClipPlanes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html): e.g. `Graphics3D[bunny[[1]], ClipPlanes -> {-1, 1, 0, 1}]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the undocumented/internal function

```
Charting`get3DPlotRange
```

That will give you the bounding box for the `Graphics3D` object. Then, you can just use `Show` with `PlotRange`. *Cf.:*

```
In[578]:= Charting`get3DPlotRange[bunny]

Out[578]:= {{-81.0932, 81.0932}, {-80.3823, 80.3823}, {-62.851, 62.851}}

Show[bunny, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 80}, {0, 62}}]
```

[image]

This should do what you want, I think. It does seem to be a little finnicky as to how these ranges actually map onto the shape, but a little fiddling should get you where you want to be without much issue. Here's what it looks like with multiple ranges:

```
GraphicsRow[Show[bunny, PlotRange -> {All, #, All}] & /@ {{-80, 80}, {0, 40}, {0,20}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]